# Populate Lookup Value based on URL

Tags: 2007

Is it possible to read the order # (which is alpha-numeric) from URL (Sharepoint document library) and automatically populate 2 drop down box only for newform

for example:
url is https://www.abc.com/sites/longhorn/SPteam23 documents/allitems.aspx

So the first drop down should be automatically populated with SP and team23 for 2nd drop down.

Answer (score 1):

You could do it by provisionning a custom NewForm.aspx and adding some Javascript that would parse the URL, and then populate the dropdown values.

Comment: hmm. Sound Good but do you have any link(s) or sample code.

Comment: I don't have specific code, right now, 'cause I never had to do it, but you could check on jQuery for the Javascript part, and check the following link to get to have a custom NewForm.aspx http://www.risetime.com/blog/archive/2009/06/03/create-a-custom-newform-aspx-for-a-sharepoint-list.aspx